# Converting a (probable) ENVI file to decimals using R or excel

Tags: r, excel, ascii, converters

I got the  output file from a spectrometer which is supposed to be a series of decimals numbers. The file looks like this:

```
™pQH1JHxþFH$ÏFH÷~EHa×BHäBHßdBH.@H²Ï=HL=HŒÚ<Hê‰:H­P:Hoõ9H¢Ž6Hº7H¨Y5H ?1H½¶.Hø²0HøŽ2H8æ.H.î,HŒt/H&1HÍ¸0Hí.Hvî,H$ª+HµX+HCý*H·W+H!º+HP+HfØ(Hû'H†Ù'H|U(HQ`)Hn*H
})H'Hó%HÂ%H¶¨&H&H|•&H\
```

I have been reading a lot without getting to the solution. My silly question is: is that a ENVI or ASCII file? Or? How can I see the numbers I need do to use? I tried some online converters without being successful.

The starting point would be to get these numbers to develop a R code to make graphs. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: ASCII files contain only numbers, the letters A-Z and a-z, and a few symbols like +-() etc (basically anything you can see on a common (US, UK) keyboard). You've definitely not got an ASCII file there...

Comment: Could be ENVI file?

Comment: The only ENVI file format I know is for spatial grid data, like satellite images. Any chance you can link us to the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you opened the binary file of the mass spectrometer. Almost all vendors keep their format a secret. The only way to do this is to export it to an open format. Most vendors supply some kind of data analysis software and there are often export functions present. Most general open data formats are mzXML and mzML.

For converting have a look at the msconvert program from [ProteoWizard](http://proteowizard.sourceforge.net/).

If you have converted the data one of the packages in R where you can start with is [XCMS](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html).

Comment: Actually this is the exported file, so it is in an open format. Could be an ENVI file? Someone told me that he got a matlab code to convert this file, so I think it is possible to do that...

Comment: Ow! ENVI doesn't ring a bell for me. From which vendor is the MS?

Comment: Should be Thermofischer.

Comment: I talked to a colleague working a lot with a LC-MS from Thermofisher, but they always use the raw data files or it is exported to mzXML / mzML format. If the ENVI file is a binary format you need to know its structure to be able read it.